# Object comparison with Sorting. C++

Tags: c++

I'm having a hard time trying to understand other people's codes here.
I would really appreciate if someone helps me.

Let's say there is an array of object : `vpair_list` and this `vpair_list` has a type of class of `vpair`. So, it would be like this:

```
class vpair
{
public:
    int vid;
    int vlabel;
};

bool operator < (const vpair& x, const vpair& y);

vpair* vpair_list;
vpair_list = new vpair[25];
..
sort(vpair_list, vpair_list+j);
```

What I know from that is `sort()` compares each element of array `vpair_list` and sorts them.

The thing is that I just can't understand how that sorting works since the object `vpair` has two different properties.

Does the sorting work like comparing each property(`vid` and `vlabel`) or....? What I thought was the sorting was supposed to be done by comparing specific field or property (either `vid` or `vlabel` here).

But this code hasn't got anything to do with that and seems like it just compares the whole object. Could someone tell me how that works?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The sorting is done by calling the operator. You've declared it, but you haven't defined it yet.

Comment: It uses `operator<`, however that is implemented...

Comment: Thank you so much guys. But what I meant was which field that 'operator <' compares. Does it compare both vid and vlabel and if so, what happens if (vpair_list[0].vid < vpair_list[1].vid) and (vpair_list[0].vlabel > vpair_list[1].vlabel)? How is it going to be sorted?

Comment: @user1643168 It compares it however you implement it. *You* decide that.

Comment: What if I don't decide which field to compare with? Is there any 'default mode'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the sorting work like comparing each property(vid and vlabel) or....?

It happens **exactly how you want** it to happen.

By default as people have mentioned, the `<` operator is used by various sort algorithms to arrange elements in **ascending order of that operator**. However for classes/structs there is **no default way** to compare them meaning **you the programmer** has to code it in.

That is what

```
bool operator < (const vpair& x, const vpair& y);
```

is. It is just a declaration to the definition of the function the programmer has provided to compare 2 `vpair` order. The programmer uses his rules to decide and ultimately returns `true` or `false`. This is used to sort.

So **you can decide** exactly how you want it to sort.

```
bool operator < (const vpair& x, const vpair& y)
{
     if(x.vid != y.vid)
        return x.vid<y.vid;

     return x.vlabel <y.vlabel;
}
```

This would sort by ascending order of ID, if they are equal, It then sorts by ascending order of vlabel.

Comment: I appreciate for your answer. Cheers~

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach:

```
class vpair
{
public:
    int vid;
    int vlabel;
};

bool operator < (vpair const& x, vpair const& y)
{
     return std::tie(x.vid, x.vlabel) < std::tie(y.vid, y.vlabel);
}
```

Of course, the operator can be a member:

```
class vpair
{
    int vid;
    int vlabel;
public:
    bool operator < (vpair const& y) const
    {
         return std::tie(vid, vlabel) < std::tie(y.vid, y.vlabel);
    }

};
```

Comment: Thank you sehe. So it compares both vid and vlabel at the same time? what if one is bigger and the other is smaller and how is it gna be sorted?

Comment: The first tuple element takes precedence. To reverse the precedence, use `std::tie(vlabel, vid)`

Comment: Using `std::tie` will compare them lexicographically, that is, it compares the first elements (in this case `vid`), if they are equal, it will compare the second elements (in this case, `vlabel`).

Answer (score 1):

Sort, by default, compares with the `operator<`.  You can implement this operator for your class like so:

```
public:
bool operator < (const vpair& other) const
{
     return (vid < other.vid); // Uses vid but this can be vlable or something else.
}
```

If you don't have an overload for the `operator<` with the class you're using, you can always pass in a comparison function as `std::sort`'s third argument:

```
bool compare_func(vpair i,vpair j) { return (i.vid < j.vid); }
sort(vpair_list, vpair_list+j, compare_func);
```